# Matching query does not exists on first time login

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch over my database.
I indexed a table called `Student`, `Student` is having a Foregin key of `User` my sample code goes like this,

index.py

```
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        related_models = [User]
        fields = ['id', 'class','classteacher']

    def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
        if isinstance(related_instance, User):
            return Student.objects.get(user= related_instance.id)
```

models.py

```
class Student(CommonBase):
    """
    Student details.

    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    classteacher = models.ManyToManyField('Teacher', null=True, blank=True)
    class = models.IntegerField( blank=True,
                                              null=True) 

class User(CommonBase, AbstractUser):


    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255, verbose_name='first name')
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic_link = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='email address')
```

When I try to login via Django admin I am getting,

```
self.model._meta.object_name
students.models.Student.DoesNotExist: Student matching query does not exist.
ERROR "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 203435
```

This happens because of this lines,

```
def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
    if isinstance(related_instance, User):
        return  Student.objects.get(user= related_instance.id)
```

ie, It tries to get "User" through "Student" while login through Django.

I made a temporary fix by putting a try catch ,

```
def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
    if isinstance(related_instance, User):
       try:
           return Student.objects.get(user= related_instance.id)
       except:
           logger.error(str(e))
```

Is there any better solutions??

Comment: can you check if Student this index exists in ES?

Comment: Yeah, I have Student in my ES